# How can I improve performance for unzip the zip file in Android

Tags: java, android, zip, unzip

I am developing diary Android application.
It has a function about backing up and restoring the diary from zip file.
I'm facing with improving the up zip behavior because it has image file (.png)
If the size of images big, To upzip is very slow.
Below is my unzip code!
Is there any other work around to improve the performance than my code?
Any comment will be appreciated!

```
public File unZip(File zipFile){
    if(!zipFile.getName().toLowerCase().contains(".zip")){
        throw new IllegalStateException("The file should be zipped");
    }
    File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File dir = new File(root, "DAISY_UNZIP");
    if(!dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdir();
    }
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ZipInputStream zis = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
        zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
        ZipEntry ze;
        int length;
        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null){
            //TODO Improve performance by using bufferedOutputStream - but, image cannot be shown when using bos.
            File nextFile = new File(dir, ze.getName());
            fos = new FileOutputStream(nextFile);
            while ((length = zis.read(buffer)) != -1){
                fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            if(bos != null) bos.close();
            if(fos != null) fos.close();
            if(zis != null) zis.close();
            if(fis != null) fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return dir;
}
```

Comment: Where / how is `buffer` declared / initialized?

Comment: Java ZIP handling is quite inefficient. Using ZLib directly you'll be able to do it better, but only in C or C++.

Comment: @StephenC buffer wa initialzed as below.

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 64 * 1024;
    private byte[] buffer;

    public ZipManager() {
        buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    }

Comment: @tynn I should use Java only.. anyway thanks!!

Comment: I don't think you will be able to improve performance if you stick with Java only.